# Find rotation angle of binary image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, mathematical-morphology

I have a set of images containing top views of solar panels as seen bellow :[image]

In order for me to get the rotation angle of the solar panels,I trained a model to segment the images as seen bellow:
[image]

In order to extract the angle of rotations I used cv2.findContours then fitline, fitellipse, minareareact but the angle various were not consistent

```
 area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        if area>max_area:
            cnt = contours[i]
            max_area = area
            
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    x, y = [], []
    ((centx0,centy0), (widthe0,heighte0), angle_200)= cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
```

I also used PCAcompute butthe angles zere notconsistent either

Now, I am following another approach in which I apply canny edge detection to extract the edges and then extract the angles:
[image]

Or this one

[image]

But even here using the different fitting techniques did not turn out to be robust.

Is there a good method to extract angles of rotations or tilt of the panels from this images?

Comment: Read about vanishing points and make use of the white grid on those panels. When the panel is parallel to the camera image plane there is no finite vanishing point anymore.

Comment: the network's output is quite coarse, and upscaled. use it only to mask the source image (ignore non-panel area), and to separate the picture into panels. -- find lines in the source picture (hough transform). the slope of a panel causes the crosswise lines to meet in a vanishing point in the picture (lengthwise lines don't). that's how you could tell the direction.